# A problem about general topology.

Tags: general-topology

> X is a compact Hausdorff. For each continuous function $f:X\to \mathbb R$, define $U_f \subset X = \{x\in X | f(x)\neq 0\}$. Prove that
>   $\{U_f \mid f:X\to \mathbb R $ continuous $\}$ forms a base for the
>   topology of X. (note: $U_f=f^{-1}((-\infty,0)\cup (0,\infty))$: open
>   in X.)

I am taking a course on topology. So I heard about compact, Hausdorff, continuous, base. But I don't know how to solve this problem. Any hint, comment or solution is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, by definition, you only have to check that for any $x\in X$ and any open set $V$ in $X$ such that $x\in V$ you can find a continuous function $f$ such that $x\in U_f\subset V$.
I will give you some hints to complete the proof:

Since $X$ is Hausdorff and compact, it is normal and that the set $\{x\}$ is closed.

If you set $f_1:\{x\}\cup X\setminus V\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f_1(x)=1$ and $f_1(p)=0$ if $p\in X\setminus V$ then $f_1$ is well defined and is continuous. Also, note that the domain of $f_1$ is closed in $X$.

You can complete the proof applying the [Tietze extension theorem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem) to get a function $f$ such that $U_f$ satisfies what we want.

Comment: I can't make peace with the sentence "Note that since $X$ is Hausdorff, it is normal ...". I know what you mean, but that sentence just looks wrong every time I read it. Admittedly, "since $X$ is a quasicompact Hausdorff space" reads a little clumsily, but I think both properties contributing to the normality should be mentioned. Nevertheless, good guidance, +1.

Comment: @DanielFischer What I don't understand is: how can one check something is a base for the topology on $X$ when one is not given a topology on $X$?